How to deserialize protobuf message containing bytes to C# objct
I'm using c#.net cote 8.0. I have a protobuf object
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "Application.Messages";

message ApplicationConfig {
 string domain = 1;
 int32 port = 2;
 string user_name = 3;
 string password = 4;     
 bytes cert = 5;
}

The auto generated class ApplicationConfig  has ByteString Cert property (which is empty in this case).
When I'm serializing to json the string I'm getting:
{"domain":"somedomain","port":123,"userName":"Administrator","password":"888888","cert":[]}

When I'm trying to deserialize it
var appConfig = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ApplicationConfig>(appConfigJson);
I'm getting a default empty object. I'm pretty sure it is related to the bytes cert .

I am failing to see the problem, yet. Are you expecting a non-empty "cert"? Where is it supposed to come from then if it's empty as you write?

Also, add the generated ApplicationConfig class code. I have 1-2 "usual suspects" ....

Protobuf has nothing to do with JSON. It's unclear what the question is - there's not even any Protobuf-related code in the question. Have you checked the protobuf-net docs? The examples there show how to serialize eg a person object created with new Person, using Serializer.Serialize(file, person); and deserialize it with newPerson = Serializer.Deserialize<Person>(file); You can deserialize from a byte[] too

May be problem is in JsonSerializer configuration? Maybe you should deserialize with ignoring case.

@Firuz protobuf isn't text at all, much less JSON. There's absolutely no way to deserialize protobuf with a JSON serializer, just as there's no way to display a photo with Notepad. Either the OP posted the wrong code or asked for the wrong thing.

^^ I am suspecting two separate issues, the latter one (json) resulting from trying to investigate the former. I'd recommend to drop the json part and instead set a breakpoint after the protobuf deserialization and then introspect the result in the debugger.

Is this a Google.Protobuf type? Note that Google.Protobuf has an inbuilt opinionated json later, designed to work with the generated types. If it is a protobuf-net type: can we see the type? Or did you codegen that via protogen? Or...? Basically: what would we need to do to repro what you're seeing? (for clarification: I'm protobuf-net, give-or-take, so: if this is actually protobuf-net related somehow, I'm all ears - bit nothing shown above uses protobuf-net; I'm guessing it is actually Google.Protobuf, though - same format, different tool)
